why and how can I generate a blank swagger page with just a authorize button?
In a API Platform 4 project, I need to provide authentication security for swagger doc.
For that, I followed this process: API Platform secure swagger
If I strictly follow the code the result is: "Full authentication is required to access this resource. (401)"
If I more open the firewall + control access I can view ALL my doc resources without any authorize control from this URL: /api (that is not the objective because is not secure)
Authorize button and process seems to be display but generate request after forbidden result because no JWT token into the request.
I also try to not displayed resource if a access in /api url with :
#[ApiResource(
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
)]

but it does nothing and resources are again displayed without authorize control
Dealing with this code can you tell me why and how can I generate a blank swagger page with just an authorize button for access after all resources information ?
security.yaml:
security:

  password_hashers:
    App\Entity\Users: 'auto'

  providers:
    users:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\Users
        property: email

  firewalls:

    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    api:
      pattern: ^/api/
      stateless: true
      provider: users
      jwt: ~

    main:
      json_login:
        check_path: auth
        username_path: email
        password_path: password
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/docs, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/auth, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
  swagger:
    api_keys:
      JWT:
        name: Authorization
        type: header

routes.yaml:
auth:
  path: /auth
  methods: ['POST']

controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

The final purpose is secure swagger display with JWT Token. It seems that the documentation lacks information or change into engine between API Platform 3 and 4.

The problem you’re encountering likely stems from the configuration not fully integrating the security setup for Swagger and API Platform. Here’s how you can address the issues step-by-step to achieve a secure Swagger UI that requires authentication via a JWT token:
To ensure that Swagger itself is secured and displays only the “Authorize” button before showing resources, you need to adjust the security.yaml and api_platform.yaml.
security.yaml Adjustments
security:
  password_hashers:
    App\Entity\Users: 'auto'

  providers:
    users:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\Users
        property: email

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    api:
      pattern: ^/api/
      stateless: true
      provider: users
      jwt: ~

    main:
      json_login:
        check_path: auth
        username_path: email
        password_path: password
        success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
        failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

    docs:
      pattern: ^/docs
      stateless: true
      provider: users
      jwt: ~

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/auth, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

Update your resource definitions to ensure proper control for unauthorized access. For example:
#[ApiResource(
    security: "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
    securityMessage: "Only admins can access this resource."
)]
class YourEntity
{
    // ...
}

This ensures the resources are hidden in the Swagger UI unless the user has the appropriate role.
Update your api_platform.yaml file to properly integrate the JWT authentication scheme into Swagger:
api_platform:
  swagger:
    api_keys:
      JWT:
        name: Authorization
        type: header
  defaults:
    pagination_client_items_per_page: true
  mapping:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
  exception_to_status:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: 403

In src/OpenApi/OpenApiFactory.php, create a custom OpenAPI definition to include the JWT Authorization button.
<?php

namespace App\OpenApi;

use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\OpenApi;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Components;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\SecurityScheme;

final class OpenApiFactory implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    private OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);

        $components = $openApi->getComponents() ?: new Components();
        $components = $components->withSecuritySchemes([
            'bearerAuth' => new SecurityScheme(
                type: 'http',
                scheme: 'bearer',
                bearerFormat: 'JWT',
            ),
        ]);

        $openApi = $openApi->withComponents($components);
        $openApi = $openApi->withSecurity([['bearerAuth' => []]]);

        return $openApi;
    }
}

Register OpenAPI Factory Service in config/services.yaml:
services:
  App\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory:
    decorates: 'api_platform.openapi.factory'

Don't forget to clear cache after all manipulations.

Nice response and I confirm that it works well BUT that not real resolve issue dealing with visibility of the resource for users auth or not. #[ApiResource(security)] seems to be handle only the request operations auth not the visiliby into swagger.

You can use Areas to separate requests onto separate docs routes. And authorize users on these routes
